# sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit() sometimes uses multiple cores. Why?

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn

I noticed that `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit()` uses multiple cores on some of my computers, and only one core in some others. What determines how many cores `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit()` will use?

I use scikit-learn version is 0.17.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 on all computers.

Comment: what are you passing in for n_jobs?

Comment: Since the question received no answer, I cross posted on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Why-does-sklearn-linear_model-LogisticRegression-fit-sometimes-uses-multiple-cores

Comment: Just a guess: the one core used machine is a windows one ? there's no posix compliant fork/thread library in windows which probably explain the behavior (maybe in windows 12, but I had no chance to try it)

Comment: @Tensibai  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 on all computers. Thanks for pointing this out, I have added the information in the question.